# Does testmempoolaccept check all possible rejection rules?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, mempool

Is there any rejection rule that `testmempoolaccept` will not check, or is it safe to assume that if it passes `testmempoolaccept` validation it will be at least broadcast?

Mostly concerned about complex reasons, such as `too-long-mempool-chain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not, or at least not at any point in time.

There are both invariant and time-dependent rules for the mempool to accept a specific transaction.

The `testmempoolaccept` command will check your transaction against the former (policy and consensus rules), but there is nothing you could realistically do to check the latter.

As an example of a time-dependent rule, you could have a software checking pre-signed transactions paying 253sat/kW of feerate against `testmempoolaccept`.
Valid transactions would pass the check, nonetheless they would not broadcast if the mempool minimum feerate is > 253sat/kW at the time of broadcast.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I was thinking more on non-transitory checks about the tx correctness, such as not double-spent, standard (ruling out fess),... I'm less concerned about transitory rejections.